# .env file variables not present during run: How to check if loaded?

Tags: docker, environment-variables

EDIT: This is solved. The answer was that in a Docker run command the options must appear before the image name; so just moving --env-file settings.env to before the image name immediately solved this.

I am trying to run a C# asp.net core webservice in a Linux Docker container that is running on Windows 10.

During debugging I am able to load the settings.env file but i cannot seem to load it when I run the container.

The settings.env file containing the following:

```
#MerConnection data
Server-James=172.25.134.49,1433
Database-James=Store
DBUser-James=user
DBPassword-James=password
ConnectionString-James=
```

And my command to run the container is as follows:

```
docker run -p 40012:80 apilive:latest --env-file 'C:\Applications\VB2017Apps\Mer .net\Mer\settings.env' -Encoding ascii
```

I am calling the environment variables thus:

```
        if (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ConnectionString-" + tenantId) == "")
        {
            string server = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Server-" + tenantId);
            string db = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Database-" + tenantId);
            string user = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DBUser-" + tenantId);
            string password = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DBPassword-" + tenantId);

            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("ConnectionString-" + tenantId, "Server=" + server + ";Database=" + db + ";User Id=" + user + ";Password=" + password + ";MultipleActiveResultSets=true");
        }


        return Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ConnectionString-" + tenantId);
```

I believe it's not loading though because on calling the webservice it reports that it's not able to create a valid connection string, which is what I'd expect if the Environment variables are null.

Unfortunately after googling and trying various edits of the docker run command e.g. with/without quotes and equals-sign etc I cannot get it to load nor give me any indication of the problem, so any help resolving this would be appreciated.

Comment: you can enter the container and then execute `echo $variablename` if its loaded it should print a value

Comment: @MostafaHussein When I try 'echo $Server-James' it prints '$Server-James' so I assume this means it hasn't loaded the variables

Comment: try to use underscore for the varaibles name so it should be `Server_James` . modify the env file then recreate the container

Answer (score -2, accepted):

After much more searching and implementing the above ideas, i found my questions was a duplicate of the following one: [How to pass through environment variables in docker run through an env file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48930991/how-to-pass-through-environment-variables-in-docker-run-through-an-env-file)

That answer also solved this one.

Comment: Just to mention, the question you asked was ".env file variables not present during run: How to check if loaded?", which is a different question than what you actually wanted.

Comment: @lucidMonkey The answer for that question was that the --env-file is an option and so is mandatory it appears before the image name; same answer here as i also placed it after the image name. funnily enough once I moved it it also started parsing it and giving feedback so was simple to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

To check if your environment variables are loaded you can use docker inspect:

```
docker inspect --format '{{ (index .Config.Env) }}' <container_id>
```

This should print a list of all your environment variables.

I don't use Docker so much in Windows environment, but you might need to escape your '\' and spaces. Also, the use of '-' in environment variables seems questionable.